# How to detect USB Mass Storage support on an android device (for example on Nexus Galaxy)?

Tags: android, usb, storage, sd-card

ICS does support usb mass storage, but Galaxy nexus doesn't. I want to be able to detect during runtime if my device supports UMS or not. Any ideas how this can be done?
I know that I can check: Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();
Would that, along with os version 4 and up check be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated() solves the problem:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageEmulated()

Answer (score 0):

You can only response to Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED or to save/read data
you can use System functions to access external storage.

more about that you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: re  Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED: i can't wait for the user to connect the usb storage to determine that, i need to know this before.

Answer (score 0):

While you connect your mobile with the PC you will autometicaly notify about to set the USB Mass Storage at the top of the Window in Notification bar..

and if you are asking about the settings in device then go to settings/Application/Development/USB debugging (Set it on for debugging)

And if you are not able to do it then install samsung kies in your pc then restart the device and PC. and try to connect it.

Enjoy. :))